# How can I extract the screen of the mobile from an image where there are other rectangular objects also?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I want to extract the screen of the mobile device from an image where mobile is not the largest rectangle. The mobile is placed on a table or mobile image is visible inside a laptop screen. So I am not able to use the largest contour detection algorithm.
If you can help please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Here I am adding a sample picture:
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rsyx.jpg)

Comment: can you add sample pictures and the code samples which you have tried so far ?

Comment: Yeah sure.. I'll upload the picture

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches that you can take:

1. Probably the most promising method will be to train a deep-learning model with your costume data. Take a look at [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-your-own-object-detector-ad69dda69c85) article.
2. You can add some other filters before searching for rectangles. For example, if your phone screen is turned off, you can use HSV color filter for black objects. I would be doing something like that:

```
blur = cv2.blur(img,(5,5))
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Play with these values. They are the HSV lower and upper bounds:
lower_black = np.array([0, 5, 50], np.uint8) 
upper_black = np.array([179, 50, 255], np.uint8)

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_black, upper_black)
# mask = cv2.Canny(mask, 60, 120) - optional
img_res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
```

(`np` refers to `numpy`).

Now try to perform contour detection on `img_res`. Notice that HSV lower and upper bounds values should be fine-tuned to give you the best results.

- If the contour detection doesn't work well on the filtered image, try to apply Canny edge detection on `mask`, as commented in the code.

Comment: hello, thanks for the help. But I have tried both contour finding and Canny edge detection but none of them worked efficiently.

Comment: Did you try color filtering as well?

Comment: I think you might want to take the first approach, using deep learning. Because you can't really determine which contour is your phone.

Comment: Which deep learning algorithm should i opt for? I tried using yolov3 for detecting mobile phones. It could detect the phone but then I need to crop the phone. And the bounding box that it returned was not very accurate.

Comment: That's great! yolov3 is very good and efficient. Now for the cropping, create a new image from the bounding box that's been detected by the model, and use a simple contour detection to crop the largest rectangle.

Comment: Actually the problem in that algorithm is that in some cases the bounding box does not comprise the entire mobile.

Comment: You can increase the bounding box for safety